# How to disable this shadow?

Tags: mesh, light, shaders, shadows

the shadow is allways to the right and I dont know why it is there.[image]

Comment: what shadow are you talking about? It looks like you need to recalculate the normals (select all in edit mode and ctrl N), maybe that's what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes omg thanks that solve my problem <3 I'm new in blender so thanks. this dark places was disturbing me xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to recalculate the normals: select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>